# Swift string padding not equal?

Tags: string, swift

(swift)

When using `String.stringByPaddingToLength` it correctly pads to the set number of characters however different lines have different padding positions due to the fact that some characters are bigger than others.

Whats happening... (unequal spacing)

```
SomeValueName:..................SomeValue  (40 characters wide)

SomeDifferentValue..........SomeValue (40 characters wide)
```

whats I need  (equal spacing)

```
someValueName:..............SomeValue (40 characters wide)

someDifferentValue...........SomeValue (40 characters wide)
```

Is it not possible for me to use `stringByPaddingToLength` to obtain this result? It seems as though it just worries about the amount of characters not actually where it ends up.

Comment: Yes, it worries only about the number of characters because it is a string method. It has now knowledge about the font you want to use to display them. This kind of method can be used only with monospace fonts, e.g. when printing to the console. Keep the label & value strings separated and use different labels for them.

Comment: Yeah I made a work around using two UITextViews but now they don't scroll together

Comment: Do not use "padding". Use NSAttributedString and tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Use tab to align you strings:

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
let terminator = NSTextTab.columnTerminatorsForLocale(NSLocale.currentLocale())
// Adjust the location as needed for your text
let tab = NSTextTab(textAlignment: .Right, location: 72.0 * 2, options: [NSTabColumnTerminatorsAttributeName: terminator])
paragraphStyle.tabStops = [tab]

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Apple:\t$1.50\nOrange:\t$1", attributes: [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle])
self.textView.attributedText = attributedString
```

This prints:

```
Apple:         $1.5
Orange:        $1
```

They align at the decimal point. I have yet to find out how to add leading dots. If somebody does, feel free to edit my answer.